# Remove Titlebar but still be able to resize

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, titlebar

I wanted to do a WPF Window and build a custom `TitleBar` without having to reimplement all the code and behaviour myself...
Only problem is that even setting the `Borderthickness` to "0" will leave a small
border on the top of the window.
Is there any way to get rid of that by **not** using `WindowStyle = "None"` ?

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to implement the resizing functionality yourself if you use the [WindowChrome](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.windowchrome(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Please refer to the documenation and the following blog post for more information: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsdk/2010/08/25/experiments-with-windowchrome/

Comment: What if WindowChrome isnt an option? Is there still a way to get the result?

Comment: Then you will have to set the WindowStyle to None and implement the resizing functionality all by yourself: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/03/16/how-to-create-a-custom-window-in-wpf/